# Need to calculating percentage increase in grouped data between 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that includes years of medical data by country - including types of illness `[column='Indicator Name']` and the remainder of columns are years from 1960 - 2015. I am trying to group and total the types of 'illness' rows together and determine the percentage increase from 1960 to 2016, and sort by highest.

I was trying to create a new DF (`df1`) with the sorted and totaled data and then determine the difference (see below). This approach is not working.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df1 = df.groupby['Indicator Name']
df1['ans4']=(df1['2015']-df1['1960'])/df1['1960']
df1.sort_values(by='ans4')
```

How can I do this?

**EDIT**
I'm adding a minimal dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
diseases = ["disease_{:02}".format(i+1) for i in range(4)]
years = list(range(1960, 1970))
df = pd.DataFrame({"disease":diseases})
df[years] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1000, 10000,(len(diseases),len(years))))
```

Comment: Including the `head` of your dataframe would help other users answer your question accurately.

Comment: import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

Comment: @Vlin I think twolffpiggott means edit your post and add the result of `df.head()` you see on your computer, and limit to the column you talk about (Indicator name, 1960 and 2015), like this we have some data to try with. Then one mistake, is that groupby is a function, so at least `df1 = df.groupby(['Indicator Name'])` with parenthesis. But then `df1` is not a Dataframe, it is a DataFrameGroupBy, and `df1['2015']-df1['1960']` (between others) is not possible.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to edit and add to the original post. Not sure if it worked, as it saved but is not showing up on refresh.

Comment: I added a dataframe to your question could you please tell us which one is the output you are looking forward.